# How to get elements inside of commented out code HtmlAgilityPack in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

Is there a way to use HtmlAgilityPack on html that is inside `<!-- -->` comment blocks? For example, how can I target the inner text of `"//div.[@class='theClass']"` that is inside a block like this:

```
<!-- <div class="theClass'>Hello I am <span class="theSpan">some text.</span> </div>-->
```

So that I get

```
Hello I am some text.
```

The reason I ask is because I kept finding that this kept returning NULL, because the `div`'s are inside comments:

```
htmlnodes = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='theClass']")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, XPath treats comment node content as plain text, means you can't query the content just like common nodes.

One possible way is to parse the comment node content as another `HtmlDocument` so you can query from it, for example :

```
'get desired comment node'
Dim htmlnode As HtmlNode = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//comment()[contains(., theClass)]")

Dim comment As New HtmlDocument()
'remove the outer <!--  --> so we have clean content'
comment.LoadHtml(htmlnode.InnerHtml.Replace("<!--", "").Replace("-->", ""))
'here you can use common XPath query again'
Dim result As HtmlNode = comment.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='theClass']")

'following line will print "Hello I am some text."'
Console.WriteLine(result.InnerText)
```

Comment: Thank you. The above does works and you answered my question.