# HtmlAgilityPack not getting all the tables

Tags: c#, webclient, html-agility-pack

using this code and  I am trying to get all of the `HTML Tables`. One of the table is commented out `<!--<table>`, I want to include that in the output. When I do this logic I am only seeing one table. Is there a way to get all table?

[image]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string SEPARATOR = ",";
    //WebClient webClient = new WebClient();



    //string page = webClient.DownloadString("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/202209110det.htm");

    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    string HTML = "<html><head>\r\n</head>\r\n<body contenteditable=\"false\">\r\n\r\n<h2>HTML Table</h2>\r\n\r\n<!--<table>\r\n  <tbody><tr>\r\n    <th>Company</th>\r\n    <th>Contact</th>\r\n    <th>Country</th>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>\r\n    <td>Maria Anders</td>\r\n    <td>Germany</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n</tbody></table>-->\r\n\r\n<table>\r\n  <tbody><tr>\r\n    <th>Company</th>\r\n    <th>Contact</th>\r\n    <th>Country</th>\r\n  </tr>\r\n  <tr>\r\n    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>\r\n    <td>Maria Anders</td>\r\n    <td>Germany</td>\r\n  </tr>\r\n</tbody></table>\r\n</body></html>";
    doc.LoadHtml(HTML);

    var tables = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table");
    int tablesCount = tables.Count();
    int x = 0;
    foreach ( var table in tables)
    {
        var rows = table.Descendants("tr")
            .Select(tr => tr.Descendants("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToList())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var row in rows)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", row));

        string tableName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.csv",table.Name, x);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tableName))
        {
            rows.ForEach(line =>
            {
                var lineArray = line.Select(c =>
                    c.Contains(SEPARATOR) ? c.Replace(SEPARATOR.ToString(), "\\" + SEPARATOR) : c).ToArray();
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(SEPARATOR, lineArray));
            });
        }
        x ++;

    }
}
```

Comment: A lot of those tables are commented out, do you count those too?

Comment: Yes I want the commented out tables too

Comment: Pleas [edit] the question to provide sample data inline (instead of link to a random site) - make sure to really srink HTML to just what you have problem with (it looks like you already knew what you need "Yes I want the commented out tables too" based on comment but for some reason excluded that detail from the question). Re-read the [mre] guidance - only necessary code and data are present as text in the post.

Comment: I updated the post let me know if it helps

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get elements inside of commented out code HtmlAgilityPack in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330801/how-to-get-elements-inside-of-commented-out-code-htmlagilitypack-in-vb-net)